# Do I need to know about registers and memories to access IO after putting OS on embedded systems like ARM

Tags: operating-system, arm, embedded, microcontroller, rtos

HI I am very new to embedded system.

1. Assume I am using ARM M series microcontroller and I am doing some
   operations with registers and memory to get sensor data from 'X'
   port.    Now I put operating system on same controller now what
   become the advantage of putting OS. Don't I need to access to
   register or memory to get sensor data from 'X' port .
2. I had seen many blogs that OS is only put to get all OS related
   feature like File management system , memory management system etc..
   is that only purpose and is that correct. Please help me that when
   should I go for putting OS on my embedded application. please don't
   send any links I had seen many links and not understanding.
3. What I thought is if I put OS on embedded system I don't need to
   know the full architecture like register banks etc.. is that
   correct. If it is correct how can I get my sensor data from 'X' port
   and how can redirect my printf to print on port instead of console .

Comment: ARM has a plethora of different cores. From few MHz bare-metal to 64 bit servers. But there are no "ARM M series microcontrollers". You likely mean ARM Cortex-M which is already a very broad family with a large spread performance spectrum. So here you already have to learn about the architecture. Then the rest. For bare-metal MCUs, you have to learn about the hardware, softwaren, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A real-time operating system (RTOS), such as FreeRTOS and uC/OS-II, is not the same thing as a general purpose operating system, such as Linux and Windows.  I'm guessing you're asking about an RTOS since you mentioned the ARM Cortex-M core.

A typical real-time operating system (RTOS) does NOT provide drivers for the microcontroller's peripherals.  By peripherals I mean the hardware timers, DMA controllers, GPIO, SPI, I2C and UART ports, for example.  So an RTOS does NOT relieve you from having to access memory-mapped registers to control the microcontroller's peripherals.  You will likely have to develop the peripheral drivers yourself.  The microcontroller's vendor  may provide a peripheral driver library that provides a more developer-friendly interface to the microcontroller's peripherals.  But the peripheral driver library is typically independent from any RTOS.

An RTOS provides you with the ability to make a multi-tasking application.  Without an RTOS your application is likely to be single threaded.  With an RTOS your application can be broken into multiple threads of execution which preempt one another when appropriate.  If your application is complex with several time-critical functions then an RTOS may be helpful because it allows you split those critical functions into independent tasks as opposed to having a complex super-loop.  An RTOS typically includes several services related to inter-task communication and synchronization such as semaphores, mutex, queues, and mailboxes.

Comment: The most prominent advantage of using a preemptive RTOS is high performance I/O, ie. avoiding polling.

Comment: open source rtoses like FreeRTOS, uC/OS-II, chibios, etc, you CAN add drivers to and some have drivers for some chips, esp if the chip vendor has done the porting.  So it is possible to not have to know the register space, etc, when you add the RTOS, but yes in general the RTOS is there to manage multiple things in a priority and performance fashion.  Someone somewhere still has to do the work to gain access to the peripherals that you want to manage in a priority or performance fashion.

Comment: And you may be the one that has to write the code on top of the RTOS that gets sensor data from X port.  So no adding an RTOS does not automatically remove that requirement.  Even with the RTOS with a driver that simply means you have an added layer of stuff and an api of some sort that you have to call to get sensor data from port X, just indirectly.

Comment: @Martin James . How can I avoid polling if I put RTOS . irrespective of RTOS I need to handle interrupts right ?

Comment: @BhavithCAcharya you can use interrupts in your non-RTOS app if you wish but, if it's an IO completion interrupt, how will you notify your main app loop/whatever of the completion?  You would have to poll some atomic/volatile flag, ie introduce delays and latency:(  With an RTOS, your interrupt can signal an event/semaphore that a thread is waiting on and, by exiting via the RTOS scheduler, have that thread become ready, (and hopefully running), as soon as the interrupt is over, so your data gets handled promptly.